# how can i show the content of my struct using a for or while? (i dont even know how to explain it, im very new at this.)

Tags: c

so what i need to do is create a function where it shows(?) the content of  struct (car[]), my problem is that i dont really know how...?, im guessing i should use a pointer but im really stuck.Should i use while or for, what is the best way to do this?.( i mainly did python so u can explain it in python if u want...)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct cars{
    char manufacturer[30];
    char model[30];
    int kub_lt;
    int year;
    int cost_euro;
};

struct cars car[]={
    {"OPEL",
    "VECTRA",
    1.8,
    1996,
    25000},

    {"FORD",
    "Monteo",
    1.8,
    2001,
    25000},

    {"FIAT",
    "Punto",
    1.4,
    2002,
    12000},

    {"HUNDAY",
    "Atos",
    1.0,
    2002,
    9000}
};
int main(void)
{
    int i,cptr;

    i=0;
    while (car[i]!="\0")
        printf("Manufacturer: %s\n",car[i].manufacturer);
        printf("Model: %s\n",car[i].model);
        printf("Kub.LT: %d\n",car[i].kub_lt);
        printf("Production year : %d\n",car[i].year);
        printf("Cost in euros :%d\n",car[i].cost_euro);
}
```

Comment: Get the length of the array.

Comment: You're not incrementing `i` in your loop.

Comment: `car[i]` is a struct, `"\0"` is a string. They'll never compare equal. Also, when you use a string in a comparison, it decays to a pointer, so you're comparing the struct to a pointer, and they'll never compare equal.

Comment: Just use a for-loop `for i ( i=0; i<n; i++ )` where n is the number of entries in the struct array.

Comment: `int kub_lt` can't be set to decimal-values - then you need to use a `float` or a `double`